# My file is locked in Excel 2007, what's going on?

Tags: microsoft-excel, troubleshooting, file-permissions

I have a excel 2007 spreadsheet that I'm sharing with some of my coworkers while we work on a project.  Recently, when I try to save the file, I get this error: "This file is locked.  Try the command again later."  I figured this was happening because one of my coworkers was doing something weird so I was being locked out.  So I copied the file and opened the copy, tried to save it again and got the same error!

What have I done to my spreadsheet and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else is saving or loading the file. Microsoft has a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129276) about this.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I read that article as well.  I didn't think this accounted for the copy as well, though?  I ended up having to create an new workbook from scratch and copy/pasting the data over.  Not ideal but it gets the job done I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a windows share issue. Someone has the file open for editing.

Comment: That's what I thought, which is why I created the copy, so I know the copy isn't opened by someone else.  I'm still getting the error on the copy!

Comment: I think simply copying the files will not get rid of sharing. You could probably start a new spreadsheet and copy the contents into it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), it should show you what else is using the file.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but unfortunately I don't have admin privs on this machine so I can't install anything.